# About the Monotone Convergence Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In this proof which is identical to the proof in my lecture notes:
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotone-convergence-theorem

Part of the proof: 
"Let $e>0$ Since L is an supremum of $a_n$ then $L-e$ is not an upper bound so you can choose a $a_N > L- e$"

Question: But doesnt choosing N such that $a_N > L-e$ imply choosing N such that $a_N \ge L$ so how can they continue to use it to state $L-e<a_n\le a_N\le L<L+e$?

Comment: It can't imply such  a thing since $L$ is an *upper bound* of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you messed up:

As you have written one defines $L:=sup_{n \in \mathbb N}(a_n)$. For every $\epsilon > 0$ you get that $L>L- \epsilon$ hence $L- \epsilon$ is $not$ an upperbound of your sequence, that is equivalent to saying: $$\exists N \in \mathbb N: a_N>L- \epsilon $$

Now it's really important to note that the sequence they are using is **increasing!** Therefore,
$$ \forall n \geq N: a_n \geq a_N$$

and one concludes $$L-\epsilon < a_N \leq a_n \leq sup_{n \in \mathbb N}(a_n) = L < L + \epsilon$$

The inequality you wrote down uses a **nondecreasing** sequence and defines $L$ to be the **infimum** of your sequence so the answer to your question how one can deduce what you stated is: "you simply can't, it's wrong in general". It seems you confused some things, I suggest you try to do the analogous inequality with the decreasing sequence to see wether you got the idea. I hope this helps.